# Apache Rewrite to remove specific path not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

We are building a new site but will still be referencing some of our old pages from our previous site that will now be given a `/_old` path after the domain. I would like to use a `Rewrite` to remove this. I have tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.edu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^_old(/.*|)$ $1 [L,NC,R]
```

But, then I access `www.mysite.edu/_old/test` it doesn't get rewritten to `www.mysite.edu/test` as expected.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First , your code should do what you expected in given test unless you didn't put `RewriteEngine on` at the top and if it is there , that means you may need to clear browser cache or a `mod_rewrite` is not enable at your server and finaly you may made a request without `www` and your rule will match against request with `www` only.

So ,I will give you two suggestions , if you've already do previous steps and you could be able to choose what suitable with you , first this code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.edu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^_old/?(.*)$  /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

The code above will redirect every thing starting with`_old` and if there is nothing after `_old` or only `/` it will go to main root directory.

If you want to use the above code , make sure you have the same path to every request when removing `_old` from URI.

Another suggestion , if you want to redirect only externally then use the same path internally , replace that code by this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.edu$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} _old
RewriteRule ^_old/?(.*)$  /$1 [L,NE,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_old%{REQUEST_URI}  -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /_old/$1 [L,NE]
```